# Which emoticons will Gmail automatically automate?

Tags: gmail

I was recently poking around all of Gmail's settings, and I noticed an option labelled `Emoticons`. Supposedly, when the option is selected, certain typed emoticons will "automatically animate". This led me wonder: **which emoticons will be animated** (and, [pseudo-question], into what images)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link has a key to emots in gmail

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=34056